# how to gain access to variable in/pass parameters to a callback with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is probably a JS question, perhaps more than a D3 question

I have several D3 visualizations on a single page, all being build from the same code. In order to have some kind of namespace, I made a class (well, a function in JS) which I instantiate. Something like the following:

```
function AlmViz(params) {
    ... 
    this.svg = this.chartDiv.append("svg")
        .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
        .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")");
        ...
}

function loadData(viz) {
    ...   
    viz.svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(level_data)
      .enter().append("rect")
             ...
     ...
}

 // I loop here and call this several times
 // with different paramters, so I get a bunch of 
 // different graphs
var viz = new AlmViz(params);
loadData(viz);

 chartDiv.svg.append("a")
    .attr("href", "#")
    .text("to change click here")
    .on("click", change);
```

I would now like to add some transitions, which requires the use of that .on("click", change). However, the change function, in all the d3 examples, that function is dependent on having access to variables that are in the current scope. How do I get access to the instance of AlmViz that corresponds to the chart that goes with a specific instance?

Note: this has been posted on the d3 Google group, but it didn't seem to be getting much attention there so I'd thought I'd come back to STO. The original post is here: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/1o4mYnMJZTA

Comment: You could save all the instances in an array/object.

Comment: yes, I thought of that, but I still don't know how to pass in the instance (or the array key) with the onChange callback

Comment: the only idea I had was to use an attribute from the link (say, an id on the <a>) and use that as an array key. It did not seem like the right approach, but perhaps its right?

Comment: Well, what exactly are you trying to do? Basically just call `loadData` with a different object that depends on the current state?

Comment: The loadData part is fine, the part I need help with is how to add an "change" event so I can do some transitions. The change function will need to use the current state of one of the AlmViz instances.

Comment: Well, the transitions and how you would make them depend on the current state and what you want to change it to. How about defining a function for each of the possible transitions and attaching the respective right one to the click event depending on the current state?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28579/discussion-between-pocketfullofcheese-and-lars-kotthoff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the current state as an argument to your change function like this:

```
.on("click", function() { change(viz); });
```